# Does too many views that are View.GONE affect the Android rendering speed?

Tags: android, performance

I have inherited a project where its user input screens are using single layout file. Depending on the type of user input required to show, a group of views are hidden or shown via `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`. I don't understand why the old programmers did this. Is there a performance gain in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official guideline about [**`Improving Layout Performance`**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts)

> Sometimes your layout might require complex views that are rarely
>   used. Whether they are item details you can reduce memory usage and
>   speed up rendering by loading the views only when they are needed.

You can use [**`ViewStub`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub). It is zero sized invisible View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resource at runtime.

Sometimes might need to re-use larger components that require a special layout. To efficiently achieve this, You can try with [**`Re-using Layouts with <include/>`**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts). Good way to share layout parts between different layout’s.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a case of performance gain as Views will not be rendered. However, I am not certain why those developers went with this approach. If there are multiple views are not going to be used then rather create two separate layouts and based on the user, inflate one or the another.